# I'm not able to configure system custom shortcut for screenshoting via flameshot

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I downloaded an `AppImage` file for version 10.2 to `~/Applications/Flameshot` so I have to configure this cmd: `~/usr/local/bin/flameshot gui`.

I'm not able to configure system custom shortcut for screenshoting via flameshot.

[image]

How can I fix this?

> > ~/usr/local/bin/flameshot gui

bash: /home/eladb/usr/local/bin/flameshot: No such file or directory

> > ~/Applications/Flameshot/flameshot gui

bash: /home/eladb/Applications/Flameshot/flameshot: No such file or directory

> > ls ~/Applications/Flameshot

Flameshot-0.10.2.x86_64.AppImage`

Comment: 1. What happens when you run this command in a terminal?

Comment: `>> ~/usr/local/bin/flameshot gui
bash: /home/eladb/usr/local/bin/flameshot: No such file or directory
>> ~/Applications/Flameshot/flameshot gui
bash: /home/eladb/Applications/Flameshot/flameshot: No such file or directory
>> ls ~/Applications/Flameshot
Flameshot-0.10.2.x86_64.AppImage`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try, in a terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/flameshot gui
```

(without `~`)

You can check where is `flameshot` located with

```
whereis flameshot
```

Comment: I must be missing something: `$~/Downloads$ /usr/local/bin/flameshot gui

bash: /usr/local/bin/flameshot: No such file or directory

$:~/Downloads$ whereis flameshot

flameshot:`